# the vertical lines of table are exceeding the text

Tags: tables

```
\newpage
\section{Maxwell Relations}
\section{Greeks Alphabet}

\begin{table}[h!]
   \centering
    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \\ \hline

Capital & Lower-case & Greek Name & English \\ \hline
A & \alpha & Alpha & a\\ \hline
B & \beta & Beta & b \\ \hline
$\Gamma$ & \gamma & Gamma & g \\ \hline
$\Delta$ & \delta & Delta & d \\ \hline
E & \epsilon & Epsilon & e \\ \hline
Z & \zeta & Zeta & z \\ \hline
H & \eta & Eta & h \\ \hline
$\Theta$  & \theta & Theta & th \\ \hline
I & \iota & Iota & i \\ \hline
K & \kappa & Kappa & k \\ \hline
$\Lambda$ &\lambda & Lambda & l \\ \hline
M & \mu & Mu & m \\\hline
N & \nu & Nu & n \\ \hline
$\Xi$ & \xi & Xi & x \\ \hline
O & Eisha latif  & Omicron & o\\ \hline
$\Pi$ & \pi & Pi & p \\ \hline
P & \rho & Rho & r\\ \hline
$\Sigma$ & \sigma & Sigma & s \\ \hline
T & \tau & Tau & T \\ \hline
$\Upsilon$ & \upsilon & Upsilon & u \\ \hline
$\Phi$ & \phi & Phi & ph \\ \hline
X & \chi & Chi & ch \\ \hline
$\Psi$ & \psi & Psi &ps \\ \hline
$\Omega$ & \omega & Omega & o \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Greek Table}
\label{Greek}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! Just remove that ``\\`` in the header: `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \\ \hline`

Comment: oh thank youuu sooooo muchhhhhh really means alot .it worked

Comment: Your code will still result in a bunch of error messages resulting from commands such as `\alpha` which can't be used outside of math mode. Use `$\alpha$` instead, just as you did in your first column. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document , which reproduce your problem and can be compiled as it is (like as MWE in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

- Please consider @ leandriis comment and also always test your MWE, before you publish it here (by this you can remove all errors in it, which are not related to your problem)
- Cause of your problem is described in the @AboAmmar comment
- As exercise, how the `tabularray` is versatile package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{M}{>{$}c<{$}}  % column with math content

\begin{document}

\section{Maxwell Relations}
\section{Greeks Alphabet}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,26} = {1pt,solid},
                 hline{3-25}   = {dashed},
                 vlines,
                 colspec={c M ll}
                 }       
Capital     & \text{Lower-case}
                        & Greek Name    & English   \\
A           & \alpha    & Alpha         & a         \\
B           & \beta     & Beta          & b         \\
$\Gamma$    & \gamma    & Gamma         & g         \\
$\Delta$    & \delta    & Delta         & d         \\
E           & \epsilon  & Epsilon       & e         \\
Z           & \zeta     & Zeta          & z         \\
H           & \eta      & Eta           & h         \\
$\Theta$    & \theta    & Theta         & th        \\
I           & \iota     & Iota          & i         \\
K           & \kappa    & Kappa         & k         \\
$\Lambda$   &\lambda    & Lambda        & l         \\
M           & \mu       & Mu            & m         \\
N           & \nu       & Nu            & n         \\
$\Xi$       & \xi       & Xi            & x         \\
O           & \text{Eisha latif}
                        & Omicron       & o         \\
$\Pi$       & \pi       & Pi            & p         \\
P           & \rho      & Rho           & r         \\
$\Sigma$    & \sigma    & Sigma         & s         \\
T           & \tau      & Tau           & t         \\
$\Upsilon$  & \upsilon  & Upsilon       & u         \\
$\Phi$      & \phi      & Phi           & ph        \\
X           & \chi      & Chi           & ch        \\
$\Psi$      & \psi      & Psi           & ps        \\
$\Omega$    & \omega    & Omega         & o         \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Greek Table}
\label{Greek}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the near future, you will be able to use `X`, `Y`, `Z` for the last three childs. At that time there will be no need to count the hline number since you can just write `hline{3-Y}`.

Comment: @L.J.R., this is very desired features. I looking forward to test it. Thank you for this nice package!

Comment: I have submitted version 2021M of tabularray package to CTAN. Now you can use `X`, `Y`, `Z` for the last three childs.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank you very muh for info. I looking forward to test this new options!